# Why is this NOT NULL constraint being violated when COALESCE() should ensure not null?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with about 20 rows.  I am trying to import data into it from a similar table in another schema.  The source table has null-valued fields.  The destination table does not allow nulls for some of them.  I am using COALESCE to replace any null values with default values.  However, when I try to import a row, I get a NOT NULL constraint violation.

If I remove all columns in my table except the primary key and the not nullable column, then the query works!

Here is the insert query:

```
insert into alarm_history_minimum
(alarm_history_pkey, area)
select alarm_pkey,coalesce(area, 'All'::character varying)
from old_public.alarm_history
where alarm_pkey = 82234;
```

Here is the minimized table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.alarm_history_minimum
(
    alarm_history_pkey bigint NOT NULL,
    area character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'All'::character varying
)
```

And here is the full table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.alarm_history
(
    alarm_history_pkey bigint NOT NULL,
    area character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'All'::character varying,
    device character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    alarm_number smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    tag character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    state smallint NOT NULL,
    message text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    alarm_date timestamp with time zone,
    charge integer,
    ack_date timestamp with time zone,
    ack_state integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    furnace character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    cooling_cover character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    heating integer,
    base character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT alarm_history_pk PRIMARY KEY (alarm_history_pkey),
    CONSTRAINT alarm_history_base_fk FOREIGN KEY (area, base)
        REFERENCES public.bases (area, base) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT alarm_history_charge_fk FOREIGN KEY (charge)
        REFERENCES public.charges (charge) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT alarm_history_cooler_fk FOREIGN KEY (cooling_cover, area)
        REFERENCES public.cooling_covers (cover, area) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT alarm_history_device_fk FOREIGN KEY (device)
        REFERENCES public.bases (alarm_device) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT alarm_history_furnace_fk FOREIGN KEY (furnace, area)
        REFERENCES public.furnaces (furnace, area) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
```

Comment: You have multiple NOT NULL columns. The postgres log should tell you the actual data which caused the error; if not the turn on full statement logging and try again.

Comment: The insert query you posted is the one that works or not?

Comment: The query I posted works in the small table but when I change the table name, it does not work with the large table.

Comment: I'm sorry.  My original question did not make it clear:  it was the area column that had the not null violation.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that my alarm_history table had a trigger.  The null value was coming from a table updated by that trigger.  That trigger has bitten me before in this conversion effort, and I forgot about.

My thanks to those who posted questions and comments, and my apologies for cluttering the list with my own idiocy.  Again.